# geopy openmapquest for Python throws GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges error

Tags: python, mapquest, geopy

I am running the following:

```
import geopy
geolocator = geopy.geocoders.OpenMapQuest(api_key='my_key_here')
location1 = geolocator.geocode('Madrid')
```

where my_key_here is my consumer key for mapquest, and I get the following error:

> GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried the same with the same result. After checking the Library, I found out, that the error is referring to the line, where the request ist build and it seems, that the API Key is not transmitted. If you add no key in the init statement, the api_key='' so I tried to change the line 66 in my own Library of the file: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/geocoders/openmapquest.py to my key.

Still no success! The key itself works, I've tested it with calling the URL that is also called in the Library: 
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key="MY_KEY"&format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=westminster+abbey

no idea why this isn't working…

Cheers.kg

Answer (score 1):

I made slight progress with fixing this one. I was able to get the query written correctly, but its the json parsing that kind of have me stumped. Maybe someone knows. I know the url is being sent correctly (I checked it in the browser and it returned a json object). Maybe someone knows how to parse the returned json object to get it to finally work.

Anyways, I had to go in the `openmapquest.py` source code, and starting from line 66, I made the following modifications:

```
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.api = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?"

def geocode(self, query, exactly_one=True, timeout=None): # pylint: disable=W0221
    """
    Geocode a location query.

    :param string query: The address or query you wish to geocode.

    :param bool exactly_one: Return one result or a list of results, if
        available.

    :param int timeout: Time, in seconds, to wait for the geocoding service
        to respond before raising a :class:`geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut`
        exception. Set this only if you wish to override, on this call
        only, the value set during the geocoder's initialization.

        .. versionadded:: 0.97
    """
    params = {
        'key': self.api_key,
        'location': self.format_string % query
    }
    if exactly_one:
        params['maxResults'] = 1
    url = "&".join((self.api, urlencode(params)))
    print url # Print the URL just to make sure it's produced correctly
```

Now the task remains to get the `_parse_json` function working.